# How to set MySQL variable inside query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to SET a variable before my MySQL query.

Here is my query.

[image]

But it throws an error:

> A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one near (SELECT)`

I need to use this variable in my query as well. How can I solve it?

Comment: IMHO there's nothing wrong in the first line (except of possibly returning multiple rows). I would say it's a bug in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If this is outside a stored procedure, `SET` won't work, why not try `SELECT... INTO` instead?

```
CREATE TABLE booking_packages (adultPrice SMALLINT UNSIGNED);

INSERT INTO booking_packages VALUES (10);

SELECT adultprice INTO @adultprice FROM booking_packages;

SELECT @adultprice;
```

Also note that unless booking_packages only has one row, you'll need a `WHERE` to ensure the query only returns one row to insert into the @adultprice session variable.

Regards,

James